# Why missing <fieldset> tag will cause controller cannot get form value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, fieldset

I am developing a WebApp which uses Spring-MVC & Thymeleaf as template engine.

In my HTML,I got a form like this

```
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"/>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"/>
  <input type="text" id="taskId" name="taskId" th:value="${taskId}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And I have a controller

```
@RequestMapping("/submit")
public void addUser(String taskId, String fname, String lname, ModelMap map) {
    //save to db...
}
```

At first I expect `taskId, fname, lname` will contains the value from the form, but they are all `null`

Finally I try to wrap all the input field by `<fieldset>`tag, and it suddenly works. i.e:

```
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"/>
    <input type="text" id="taskId" name="taskId" th:value="${taskId}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would like to know:

**Why adding `<fieldset>` will make everything works?**

Comment: There is no reason that a fieldset makes everything work.  There is something else happening.

Comment: @Metroids As it works after adding fieldset, so I suspect it is the reason. If not, what is happened? Thanks

Comment: I don't know.  Have you tried using chrome inspector to check the values of your post are the same before and after adding fieldset?  Have you viewed the source in the browser after running thymeleaf and verified form `<inputs>` look the same in both cases?  `<fieldset>` has nothing to do with the actual post of a form, so it's highly unlikely that it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML - `<fieldset>` tag is **used to group related elements in a form**.
Basically the `<fieldset>` tag draws a box around the related elements in a form.
Most online forms are poorly designed, disorganized, and hard to use. One thing you can do to make your forms better is to organize them into logical sections. The `<fieldset>` element provides an easy way to break forms down into logical sections.
For more information you can always got to - https://html.com/tags/fieldset/